# Binding generic list of objects to ListView and then updating the bound list

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I've got a ListView that is bound to a generic list of objects that I've created.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwConfig" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <br />
        <div class="title_small">
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'/>
        </div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="iFirstValue" runat="server" MaxLength="8" Text='<%#Eval("FirstValue")%>'></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="iSecondValue" runat="server" MaxLength="8" Text='<%#Eval("SecondValue")%>'></asp:TextBox><br /> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="iThirdValue" runat="server" MaxLength="8" Text='<%#Eval("ThirdValue")%>'></asp:TextBox><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>


protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Loop through each item in the listview
    for (int i = 0; i < lvwSMSConfig.Items.Count(); i++)
    {
        //Some code to check to see if the value was updated
        //If it was, call UpdateItem
        lvwSMSConfig.UpdateItem(i,true);
    }
}


protected void lvwSMSConfig_ItemUpdating(Object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox iFirstValue= (TextBox)lvwSMSConfig.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("iFirstValue");
    TextBox iSecondValue= (TextBox)lvwSMSConfig.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("iSecondValue");
    TextBox iThirdValue= (TextBox)lvwSMSConfig.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("iThirdValue");

    myObjectList[e.ItemIndex].FirstValue= iFirstValue.Text;
    myObjectList[e.ItemIndex].SecondValue= iSecondValue.Text;
    myObjectList[e.ItemIndex].ThirdValue= iThirdValue.Text;
}
```

The above code (modified some bits for public posting) works just fine, however I am unsure if this is the best way to achieve my goal. Is there a more direct rout that I should be taking?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, no this isn't the "easiest" way.

Have you considered using a datasource control?  Something such as a ObjectDatasource or SQLDataSource  control prove very helpful in such cases.

There are other templates you can use for instance, an Update should use the `EditItemTemplate`.  I did a quick search to get you a link to some more detailed information about how to best utilize the Listview control.  You will notice for instance you wont have to do `FindControl` calls.    [Link](http://www.dbtutorials.com/display/listview-editing.aspx)